# Canon EOS T5 Can't Read 128gb MicroSD, but can read other cards

Tags: canon, storage, microsd

Like the title says, when I attempt to use my new 128gb PNY MicroSD card, I get the message "Card cannot be accessed", where my 16gb sandisk SD still works fine. If I try to format I get the error: "Cannot format change card".

The card works fine with my computer, so at first I thought it was a problem with the formatting. I found a tool and reformatted the drive into FAT32 which my other card is using, however I still got the same error message. Am I doing something wrong?

*Update*: I tried partitioning the card below 32gb, and I still got the same issues.

*Update 2*: I borrowed another 128 msd from someone else and the camera works just fine with it. I'm going to check how this drive is formatted.

Comment: There is a chance the maximum GB for that camera are 64.  For example on some powershoot cameras the max is 32 gb. https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=FAQ100296 But I can not find the max for EOS cameras.

Comment: Would it possible to partition the drive or limit it to 64 or 32gb to get around this?

Comment: @Rafael Please try to refrain from posting answers as comments. http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge

Comment: Have you tried using the microSD card in a different microSD to SD adapter?

Comment: @MichaelClark I only have the one, but I'm assuming it isn't the problem because my computer has no issues with it.

Comment: It was an answer, but as I have no idea... It is not an answer.

Comment: Seeing as "small"  i.e. <64Gb SD cards are cheaper than a Starbucks regular,  just buy another one already!  :-)

Comment: Interesting that the user manuals make no mention of a max addressable card size!

Answer (score 1):

I have a T3i - the two generations older camera - and it handles 128 GB without issues. That is not a proof, but a strong indication that the T5i would too.

If you google for `128 GB T5i`, there are many combo offers that offer a 128 GB card together with the T5i camera.

I would assume that the speed class is insufficient, or the card or converter has an issue - or the camera has an issue.

Comment: It is just a T5, but I don't know if that would matter.
And for clarity, the speed is 85mb/s, The card works with other devices, and the camera works with other cards

Comment: ops missed that non existing 'i' - they are offered too, though: http://www.ebay.com/itm/128GB-CLASS-10-SD-SDXC-MEMORY-CARD-FOR-CANON-EOS-REBEL-T5-CAMERA-/221898524323

Comment: The OP's "update" makes this question moot;  but your info appears to be correct.